# Apple Mail not Opening Chrome links in Background

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, google-chrome

Just upgraded to the latest Chrome for Mac (Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit), running the latest macOS High Sierra (10.13.6), and that combo seems to have lost the ability to open links in the background from Apple's Mail.app. My Desktop running plain old "Sierra" seems to have the same issue. I realize now how many time a day I do that while reading email and now that I've lost that functionality, I really miss it.

My fear is a coding issue with Chrome could fix this, but I think there is a clear Apple/Google feud.

Is there a workaround or fix?

Comment: It's really annoying that they removed that feature. I used it 99% of the time when clicking links in Mail.